# Filtering SignalR ping messages

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-7.0

In my ASP.NET SignalR (.NET 7 WebApplication with Serilog), logs keep filling up with:

> [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/hubs/agentshub?id=su3OANTvP1YtU2i90eK1rA - 11

> [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/hubs/agentshub?id=su3OANTvP1YtU2i90eK1rA - 11 - 200 0 text/plain 1.1589ms

As there are no other messages from the hub before or after these messages, I assume these are simply SignalR internal pings. As seems to be evident from more verbose logging.

My question is how to filter out these ping messages while keeping other SignalR hub request messages?

I tried:

```cs
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug);
```

But no luck.

Comment: Are you using ServerSentEvents? That's the only way you would get pings in a POST. You could look at using WebSockets or LongPolling which would avoid this entirely.

Comment: No I am not using server send events

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet add package Serilog.Expressions
```

Then:

```cs
    .Filter.ByExcluding("RequestPath like '/hubs/agentshub%'")
```

(You might need to tweak the expression depending on the structure of the events/what identifies a ping, exactly.)